# Recursively merge list of lists based on shared elements

Tags: haskell

I don't know what the official technical name is for what I'm trying to do so I'll try to explain it as best I can.

Given a list of lists:

```
[[2,3,4,5], [1,5,6], [7,8,9]]
```

I want to union only the lists that have atleast one common element. So basically something like this:

```
simUnion :: [[Int]] -> [[Int]]
simUnion list = --...

--Result
-- [[1,2,3,4,5,6], [7,8,9]]
```

The problem I'm running into is running a match process between each element. Basically this is like the old math class problem where each person in a room must shake the hand of each other person. Ordinarily I'd accomplish this with a nested for loop, but how can I do this using Haskell's recursion?

Any help at all would be great!

Comment: maybe you can explain how you would want to do it? For example can you write a function that will merge two? Can you write one that decides if two are mergable? Start from there.

Answer (score 1):

If there is a finite number of distinct elements, you can turn the task inside out and make a `Ord elem => Map elem [[elem]]` out of your `[[elem]]` and then start iteratively merging the elements by the next algorithm:

1. while map isn't empty, take away a key, put it in the queue
2. get all the groups containing key popped from the queue
3. concat them and put into the queue (and in some accumulator, too)
4. if the queue got empty, the group is finished; take another key from the map

Comment: so which queue is this? ... How do deal with Queues in Haskell? ... I don't think this will help dopatraman much ...

Comment: Not sure I understand... while i can see a list of lists being treated as a map i believe such a metaphor is overkill. There is a way to frame the handshake problem using simple list functions like `head` and `cons`. Either way, i dont think I understand how your solution would solve the problem...

Comment: @Carsten, there are some queues about, and `Data.Sequence` is available everywhere, and implementing Okasaki-style banker's queues is really easy.

Comment: @dfeuer yeah I know - I just wanted to encourage Heimdell to improve on his answer - right now it does not seem to useful IMO - indeed it looked a bit like a slopy copy&paste job to me - so I tried to ask for clarification (probably in a somewhat nasty and unclear way - sorry)

Answer (score 1):

<sup>Note: The following post is written in literate Haskell. Save it as `*.lhs` and load it in GHCi. Also note that the discussed algorithm has runtime O(n²) and isn't optimal. A better approach would use [union find](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure) or similar.</sup>

First, let us think about the tools we need if we want to group a single list `x` with the rest of the lists `xs`. We need to separate between the lists from `xs` that have an element in common with `x`, and we need to build the `union` of such lists. Therefore, we should import some functions from `Data.List`:

```
> import Data.List (partition, union)
```

Next, we need to check whether two lists are suitable to get merged:

```
> intersects :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> Bool
> intersects xs ys = any (`elem` ys) xs
```

Now we have all the tools at hand to define `simUnion`. The empty case is clear: if we don't have any lists, the result doesn't have any list either:

```
> simUnion :: Eq a => [[a]] -> [[a]]
> simUnion []     = []
```

Suppose we have at least two lists. We take the first one and check whether they have any element in common with any other list. We can do so by using `partition`:

```
> simUnion (x:xs) = 
>   let (common, noncommon) = partition (intersects x) xs
```

Now, `common :: [[a]]` will only contain those lists that have at least one element in common. There can be two cases now: either `common` is empty, and our list `x` has no element in common with any list from `xs`:

```
>   in if null common 
>         then x : simUnion xs
```

We ignore `uncommon` here, since `xs == uncommon` in this case. In the other case, we need to build the union of all lists in `common` and `x`. This can be done with `foldr union`. However, this *new* list must be used in `simUnion` again, since it may have new intersections. For example, in

```
simUnion [[1,2], [2,3], [3,4]]
```

you want to end up with `[[1,2,3,4]]`, not `[[1,2,3],[3,4]]`:

```
>          else simUnion (foldr union x common : noncommon)
```

Note that the result will be unsorted, but you can `map sort` over it as a last step.

Answer (score 1):

I have two main recommendations:

1. Don't think of it in terms of recursion!  Instead, make liberal use of library utility functions.
2. Use appropriate data structures!  Since you're talking about membership tests and unions, sets (from the `Data.Set` module) sound like they would be a better choice.

Applying those ideas, here's a fairly simple (though perhaps very naïve and suboptimal) solution:

```
import Data.Set (Set)
import qualified Data.Set as Set

simUnion :: Set (Set Int) -> Set (Set Int)
simUnion sets = Set.map outer sets
  where outer :: Set Int -> Set Int
        outer set = unionMap middle set
            where middle :: Int -> Set Int
                  middle i = unionMap inner sets
                      where inner :: Set Int -> Set Int
                            inner set
                                | i `Set.member` set = set
                                | otherwise          = Set.empty

-- | Utility function analogous to the 'concatMap' list function, but
-- for sets.
unionMap :: (Ord a, Ord b) => (a -> Set b) -> Set a -> Set b
unionMap f as = Set.unions (map f (Set.toList as))
```

Now using your example:

```
-- | This evaluates to:
--
-- >>> simUnion sampleData
-- fromList [fromList [1,2,3,4,5,6],fromList [7,8,9]]
sampleData :: Set (Set Int)
sampleData = Set.fromList (map Set.fromList sampleData')
    where sampleData' :: [[Int]]
          sampleData' = [[2,3,4,5], [1,5,6], [7,8,9]]
```

> Ordinarily I'd accomplish this with a nested for loop, but how can I do this using Haskell's recursion?

You don't use recursion directly.  You use higher-order functions like `Set.map` and `unionMap`.  Note that these functions are analogous to loops, and that we're using them in a nested manner.  Rule of thumb: imperative for loops very often translate to functional map, filter, reduce or similar operations.   Nested imperative loops correspondingly often translate to nested use of such functions.